# Smoothing shrinkwrap result

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to wrap a plane around the stl of a city, in order to obtain a watertight geometry from a poorly defined base file.

Shrinkwrap is pretty awesome for that, but I'd like to improve it further and be able to smooth the jaggy edges I get, see pics below:

The shrinkwrapped version
[image: Shrinkwrapped]

The original
[image: original]

Does anyone know a trick to improve the quality a bit ? Here is what I've tried:

- Increasing subdivision helps but does not completely solves the jaggyness
- Smoothing did not work well
- I tried projecting back with additionnal shrinkwraps horizontally with distance limiter but it wasn't robust at all...
- Rhino has a drape tool that does this with a nurbs approach but I couldn't find any equivalent in blender.
- Other CAD packages have the ability to "snap" to a surface, which might solve the issue, but I could not find anything equivalent in Blender.

Thanks !

---

Edit : Following advices in comment, adding a second subsurf does smooth well. The result is now identical to Rhino Drape tool.
[image]

Comment: You can try to use 2 subsurf modifiers in the stack: one with "simple mode" before shrinkwrap (for adding geometry), another one after it (for smoothing). Maybe add "corrective smooth" modifier before second subsurf. Also try 2 shrinkwraps at the same time, one in "project mode", second in "nearest surface mode", put another subsurf in between.  You might want to try "remesh" modifier

Comment: Also, if you need to reduce unnecessary geometry at some point, add a decimate modifier un planar mode.

Comment: @SergeL thanks a lot, remesh is not an option I think since it would retain the original imperfections of the model. The key here is the ability to fill all gaps, hence the wrapping approach

Comment: Another thing worth to try: dense distribution of particles along STL file with metaball instancing. Metaballs will merge into single object

Comment: @L0Lock that'd be very useful since adding to much division ends up with a very heavy file. However the decimation itself is a bit long... 60 minutes and counting so far.

Comment: @SergeL I tried applying the tutorial I saw but got stuck pretty quickly... If you have specific instructions that's be great ! thanks a lot for the idea anyway, it looks promising indeed

Comment: Idea might not be bad, but converting many particles to metaballs and then metaballs to mesh turned up to be very time consuming (single threaded process). Anyway, If you want to try: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50779. What is much quicker - is to create point cloud from particles, but that involves combining mesh in MeshLab or similiar app with unpredictable results.